# China Password policy In Magento using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, magento, passwords

### **Main Question:**

How to implement the validation for Password can not contain strictly increasing digits/characters such as 1234/abcd, strictly decreasing digits/characters such as 4321/dcba, strictly repeating such as aaaa, or continuing keyboard such as qwer. IN PHP and Javascript

---

### **Question Detail:**

Today our client ask us to implement the password strength according to the Chinese government policy. This policy mainly have the following conditions

1. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters.
2. If password length is < 10 then it should have all four classes of characters
3. If password length is >= 10 then it should have at least two classes of characters
4. The password can not contain first name, last name, Date of birth and telephone number.
5. Password can not contain strictly increasing digits/characters such as 1234/abcd, strictly decreasing digits/characters such as 4321/dcba, strictly repeating such as aaaa, or continuing keyboard such as qwer
6. Last 5 times used password not allowed
7. Notify customer to change password withing 90 days
8. Encrypt user information (first name, last name, telephone, and DOB) in DB and then decrypt to display at front end.

I am implmenting one by one and only seeing the issue for the rule 5. But if you have any idea about any script or tutorial that explain in detail for password strength according to the Chinese government policy then please recommend me.

Currently i have implemented the rules 1-4. In Javascript and for Magento developers I override the javascript class lib/web/mage/validation.js.

```
"validate-customer-password": [
            function (v, elm) {
                var validator = this,
                    length = 0,
                    counter = 0;
                var passwordMinLength = $(elm).data('password-min-length');
                var passwordMinCharacterSets = $(elm).data('password-min-character-sets');
                var pass = $.trim(v);
                //Added By Abbas
                var firstname = $('#firstname').val().toLowerCase();
                var lastname = $('#lastname').val().toLowerCase();
                var phoneNumber = $('#phone_number').val();
                var dob = $('#dob').val();
                var lowerPass = pass.toLowerCase();
                //End Added By Abbas
                //Validation of strictly increasing, decreasing and repeating
               //Validation of strictly increasing, decreasing and repeating
            if(pass.match(/^(?=\d{4}$)(?:(.)\1*|0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?|9?8?7?6?5?4?3?2?1?0?)/)){
                result = false;
                validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                    "Password can not contain strictly increasing, decreasing or repeating sub string." +
                    " Example: 1234, 4321, 44444."
                );
                return result;
           }

                var result = pass.length >= passwordMinLength;
                if (result == false) {
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols." +
                        " Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored."
                    ).replace('%1', passwordMinLength);
                    return result;
                }
                if (pass.match(/\d+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[a-z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[A-Z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }

                /**
                 * Changed by Abbas to add the character classes validation based on the password length
                 */
                if (pass.length < 10 && counter < 4) {
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1." +
                        " Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."
                    ).replace('%1', 4);
                    return result;
                }
                if (pass.length >= 10 && counter < 2) {
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1." +
                        " Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."
                    ).replace('%1', 2);
                    return result;
                }

                //Validation of personal information
                if((firstname.trim() != '' && lowerPass.includes(firstname)) ||
                    (firstname.trim() != '' && lowerPass.includes(lastname)) ||
                    (phoneNumber.trim() != '' && pass.includes(phoneNumber)) ||
                    (dob.trim() != '' && pass.includes(dob))){
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Pasword can not contain personal information." +
                        " Personal Information: First Name, Last Name, Date of birth, phone number."
                    );
                    return result;
                }


                return result;
            }, function () {
                return this.passwordErrorMessage;
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Don't expect us to do your homework for you without you showing what you've done

Comment: @JaromandaX I have implemented the rules 1-4 and also 6-8 can implement easily.  I will edit the question and add the current implementation.

Comment: Sounds like you need the *mother of all regexes*.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added my current implementation.

Comment: @JayGould you are right it is a China government new policy :). And I am thinking how people will remember their password. It is little bit similar to the Yahoo password policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the issue but without any regular expression. It is in JavaScript

```
var pass = $.trim(v);//Password

 var firstname = $('#firstname').val().toLowerCase();
 var lastname = $('#lastname').val().toLowerCase();
 var phoneNumber = $('#phone_number').val();
 var dob = $('#dob').val();
 var lowerPass = pass.toLowerCase();
 var increasingNumber = '0123456789';
 var decreasingNumber = '9876543210';
 var increasingAlphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
 var decreasingAlphabets = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba';
 var increasingQwerty1 = '`1234567890-=\\qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;\'zxcvbnm,./ ';
 var increasingQwerty2 = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?';
 var decreasingQwerty1 = ' /.,mnbvcxz\';lkjhgfdsa][poiuytrewq\=-0987654321\`';
 var decreasingQwerty2 = ' ?><MNBVCXZ":LKJHGFDSA}{POIUYTREWQ|+_)(*&^%$#@!~';
 var passParts = new Array();


 if(pass.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{3,}/)){
     result = false;
     validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Same Character can not repeat four times." +
                        " Example: aaa,DDDD, 44444."
                    );
                    return result;
}

var result = pass.length >= passwordMinLength;

    if (result == false) {
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols." +
                        " Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored."
                    ).replace('%1', passwordMinLength);
                    return result;
                }
                if (pass.match(/\d+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[a-z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[A-Z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }

                /**
                 * Changed by Abbas to add the character classes validation based on the password length
                 */
                if (pass.length < 10 && counter < 4) {
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1." +
                        " Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."
                    ).replace('%1', 4);
                    return result;
                }
                if (pass.length >= 10 && counter < 2) {
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1." +
                        " Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."
                    ).replace('%1', 2);
                    return result;
                }

                //Validation of stricly increasing and descreasing
                for(var i =0; i <= pass.length-4 ; i++)
                {
                    if(i+4 <= pass.length)
                    {
                        passParts[i] = pass.substring(i, i+4);
                    }
                }

                for(var i =0; i< passParts.length; i++)
                {
                    if(decreasingNumber.includes(passParts[i]))
                    {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly increasing, decreasing or repeating sub string." +
                            " Example: 1234, 4321"
                        );
                        return result;
                    }else if(increasingNumber.includes(passParts[i]))
                    {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly increasing, decreasing or repeating sub string." +
                            " Example: 1234, 4321"
                        );
                        return result;
                    }else if(increasingAlphabets.includes(passParts[i]))
                    {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly increasing, decreasing or repeating sub string." +
                            " Example: abcd, dcba, ABCD, DCBA"
                        );
                        return result;
                    }else if(decreasingAlphabets.includes(passParts[i]))
                    {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly increasing, decreasing or repeating sub string." +
                            " Example: Example: abcd, dcba, ABCD, DCBA."
                        );
                        return result;
                    }else if(increasingAlphabets.toUpperCase().includes(passParts[i]))
                    {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly increasing, decreasing or repeating sub string." +
                            " Example: abcd, dcba, ABCD, DCBA"
                        );
                        return result;
                    }else if(decreasingAlphabets.toUpperCase().includes(passParts[i])) {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly increasing, decreasing or repeating sub string." +
                            " Example: Example: abcd, dcba, ABCD, DCBA."
                        );
                        return result;
                    }else if(increasingQwerty1.includes(passParts[i]) || increasingQwerty2.includes(passParts[i]) || increasingQwerty1.toUpperCase().includes(passParts[i]) || increasingQwerty2.toUpperCase().includes(passParts[i]))
                    {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly increasing qwerty sub string." +
                            " Example: Example: qwer, QWER etc.."
                        );
                        return result;
                    }else if(decreasingQwerty1.includes(passParts[i]) || decreasingQwerty2.includes(passParts[i]) || decreasingQwerty1.toUpperCase().includes(passParts[i]) || decreasingQwerty2.toUpperCase().includes(passParts[i]))
                    {
                        result = false;
                        validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                            "Password can not contain strictly decreasing qwerty sub string." +
                            " Example: Example: rewq, REWQ etc.."
                        );
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                //Validation of personal information
                if((firstname.trim() != '' && lowerPass.includes(firstname)) ||
                    (firstname.trim() != '' && lowerPass.includes(lastname)) ||
                    (phoneNumber.trim() != '' && pass.includes(phoneNumber)) ||
                    (dob.trim() != '' && pass.includes(dob))){
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Pasword can not contain personal information." +
                        " Personal Information: First Name, Last Name, Date of birth, phone number."
                    );
                    return result;
                }


                return result;
```